# Enabling Zombie Objects causing memory pressure crashing

Tags: ios, out-of-memory, exc-bad-access, nszombie

My app is crashing when its deallocating a ViewController.  I believe there is an object in there causing it - I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash.

It happens usually after finishing a level of the game and returning to the menu.

In trying to diagnose the issue, I turned on Enable Zombie Objects in the Schemes.  As I play the level to recreate the issue my memory fills up and I start getting a 'Got memory pressure notification (critical)' warning.  And then the app crashes with a  'Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue'

Is there a way to enable Zombie Objects on just one ViewController and it's contents so I'm not retaining objects I know don't matter?

Or does anyone have suggestions for what I could try other then Zombies?

Or any other advice?

Thanks, 
-Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no surprise here.

Zombies *are memory leaks*. That is exactly how they work. The *whole idea* is that no objects go out existence. That is what it means to be a zombie!

Thus, if you run the app for too long with zombies on, you will leak so much memory that you crash.

> can i enable zombie object on individual objects

No, that's not an option. You could perhaps try to make a highly reduced version of your app, one that produces the issue but with less memory usage, and run zombies on that.

Comment: Zombies are a great tool, but it might be better to start by thinking about your code. Your question didn't include any code or crash log, though, so no further help is possible in that regard. The only other hint I can provide is that this sort of crash is usually, though not always, caused by multithreading issues or mismanagement of a (nonArc) `weak` delegate.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I started looking through the code first and then moved to Zombie objects. Zombies are not my first and only stop.  I've been picking through looking for mismanaged object memory.  I've been picking through the debug trace and trying to get info through that.  I am not including crash logs because they don't help answer my primary question - can i enable zombie object on individual objects - because yes, it retains all the memory and thus crashes.  In asking for any other advice, I am simply asking if anyone has another useful approach.

Comment: "can i enable zombie object on individual objects" Okay. Well, you can't.

Comment: I will see your "No" and raise you a "that sucks"  Thanks for the input.  Appreciated.

Comment: @MarkA. I think if we think about it we can see what the problem is with the idea of per-class zombies. That's probably just not how compilation / memory management works. It can't be turned on/off per file like ARC in Objective-C. Still, I'd encourage you to file an enhancement request with Apple, as the idea is very obviously a good one.

Comment: Also I'd encourage you to post a question here about the actual crash; it may be that someone can help track it down, though of course things are notoriously tricky because the crash _itself_ is usually diagnostic of something that went wrong some time previously.